# Accidentally deleted superuser from CyanogenMod installation. How can I re-install superuser again?

Tags: cyanogenmod, superuser

I have rooted galaxy s3, but I somehow deleted superuser. I still have CWM, and my phone can boot into download mode. Am I able to flash CyanogenMod without bricking my phone?

Answer (score 3):

Because you still have a working CWM, you can just reflash it.

There are 2 competing implementations:

- [SuperSU](http://download.chainfire.eu/298/SuperSU) from Chainfire
- [Superuser](http://androidsu.com/superuser/) from ChainsDD

Most rooting utilities install the latter, so you're safe to also flash this.